# Get current URL in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I am making a website in visual studio 2010 (in visual basic) and I really need to know how to get the URL from a VB statement (in the aspx.vb file, on page load).

Answer (score 19):

There's a [few properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url(v=vs.110).aspx) that can give you the information. Here's an example.

```
Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
Dim host As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET

```
Imports System.Net.Dns
Imports System.Net

Dim host As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host)
Dim ip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
Label1.Text = ip(1).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> **.Html Page**

```
 <div>
   <h1>  Url: </h1>  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

> **in .Vb Page**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Request.Url.ToString();

    }
```